# Getting localStorage is not defined in Next.js for initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, redux-toolkit

I am creating a project in Next.js with Redux Toolkit. I tried to use `localStorage` and got the error 'localStorage is not defined', so I moved to `cookies-next` but here also getting a problem. Kindly check my `themeSlice` page:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { getCookie, hasCookie, setCookie } from 'cookies-next'
const initialState = {
    name: hasCookie('theme')?getCookie('theme'):'light'
}
export const Theme = createSlice({
    name: "theme",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        toggleTheme: (state, action) => {
            if(state.name === "light") {
                state.name = "dark"
                setCookie('theme', 'dark')
            } else {
                state.name = "light"
                setCookie('theme', 'light')
            }
        }
    }
})
export const {toggleTheme} = Theme.actions
export default Theme.reducer
```

Here in `initialState`, I am getting 'light' every time, even cookies getting set to dark with reducer.
The problem is `getCookie` is not working in initialState. It returns undefined every time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely because the getCookie function is being called before the cookie is set in the reducer. To fix this, you can use the useEffect hook in a Next.js component to retrieve the value of the cookie after it has been set:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';

function YourComponent() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  useEffect(() => {
    const cookie = getCookie('theme');
    if (cookie) {
      setTheme(cookie);
    }
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

This way, the value of the theme state will be updated with the value of the cookie after it has been set.

And the code seems fine, however, there are a few optimizations that can be made:

Use object destructuring in the initialState:

```
const initialState = {
    name: hasCookie('theme') ? getCookie('theme') : 'light',
};
```

Instead of using an if-else statement in the toggleTheme reducer, you can use a ternary operator:

```
toggleTheme: (state) => {
    state.name = state.name === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    setCookie('theme', state.name);
},
```

You can also use the spread operator to create a new object instead of mutating the existing state:

```
toggleTheme: (state) => {
    const newState = {
        ...state,
        name: state.name === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
    };
    setCookie('theme', newState.name);
    return newState;
},
```

These optimizations will help you write clean and optimized code.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need cookie data in initialState only. Because in my project there is too many things. ThemeSlice is just a little example.

Comment: You can use the useEffect hook in your Next.js component to initialize the initial state of your Redux store with the value of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error because NextJS runs on the NodeJS server first. NodeJS doesn't have `window.localstorage` object. So you need to check if `window` object is available and only then call methods on it.

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // Client-side-only code
}
```

Also, I recommend you to use [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) it's an abstraction for `localstorage`.
Here is a good [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/managing-persistent-states-in-nextjs-with-redux-toolkit-e4d4ca7c157d) that explains how to use redux-toolkit and redux-persist with NextJS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the dark mode, and I found three solutions, from best to worst.

The first one, is removing the dark mode Redux slice and handling the themes using the `next-themes` package instead. It allowed me to do everything I was doing before with Redux Toolkit but better. Effective, simple to implement (two lines of code), and customizable. It also avoids the "flickering" effect during the loading of the page, which is an annoying flash happening when the page is temporarily loaded with the wrong theme.

The second one, using only Redux Toolkit, is setting a default initial value (e.g. `initialValue: true`), and then using the `useEffect` hook on the client to set the theme according to the user's preference with the value stored inside the `localStorage`. This solution does NOT create hydration issues, however, it has the "flickering" effect problem.

The third one, which is not ideal, is dynamically loading the whole page using the `dynamic()` function of `next/dynamic` and disabling `SSR` with the option `{ ssr: false }`. It works, but you lose the `SSR` benefits of Next.js.